# Discord.py embedding messages?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do you embed messages with discord.py, i don't know why but whenever I Google this question it doesn't come up with what I'm looking for. I am just looking for either an article or example on what functions and syntax to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed),
also here's a useful visualization
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation will show you all the properties and syntax possibilities for making an embed.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed

If you wanted a step by step tutorial on how go about making an embed, there are videos on youtube that could possibly help you. I linked one below that seems relevant to this day and should work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKQWxAaRgG0

Answer (score 0):

If you are too bored to read the documentation a good website could be:

https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/

This is rather learning by doing/experimenting as you just have to set/input all the things you want to have in your embed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code on how to make an embed. The only thing that is required is the title, the other things are not needed.

```
embed = discord.Embed(
title="Embed!", description=f"Description",colour=member.colour)
embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
embed.add_field(name="New field", value="idk")
embed.set_image(url="idk.png")
embed.set_footer(text="random text bloop bloop", url="not-funny.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to read the discord.py documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=embed
(this is all the information about embeds)

An example of an embed I made is:

```
    ban_embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Color.magenta()
    )
    ban_embed.set_author(name='Ban!!')
    ban_embed.add_field(name=f'You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name}',
                        value=f'Reason = {reason}. If you want to appeal this please DM an Admin or Manager', 
                        inline=False)
```

If you are looking for youtube tutorials, the other answer has a good one linked, and the one below is another good one that I have used as well.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CQbX4XDRIw

In embeds, the only required part is the title, however you can add many different elements to it, and these are all shown in the link to the documentation I put above.